# How much time it takes to transfer an Australia visa to a new passport using Form 929?

Tags: visas, passports, australia

I have a business visa for Australia valid till end of this year(2019) but the passport it is linked to is about to expire. I have applied for a new passport which I will get within the next 14 days. As soon as I get my new passport, I will submit Form 929.

My problem is, I have to travel to Sydney, Australia as early as possible but I am not sure how much time it takes to process Form 929. Some say it takes 3 days, some say more. I need to factor this to book my Flight & Hotel early to save on cost.

Comment: You can update your passport details online via ImmiAccount instead of lodging a Form 929: https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/change-in-situation/passport-details

Comment: I applied for the visa using a paper application and my Application ID begins with 'IRIS'.

As per https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/applying-online-or-on-paper/online#content-index-14, I cannot import this type of visa to ImmiAccount.

For me, 929 is the only way.

Comment: @sandeep How did you know that the details changed ?

Comment: I checked my details on myVEVO app using my new passport number. Earlier, the query used to fail with the new passport but was successful with the old passport. 

After check-in staff transferred the visa, the query with the new passport number was successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automatic reply given when you submit a paper Form 929 is that it now takes approximately **4 weeks** to process.

[image]

Comment: Interestingly, when the service was launched just last year, the promised timeframe was 5 business days.  The current "2 weeks" may just be padding, as in my experience Oz immigration is *faster* than the estimates given.  https://www.peakmigration.com.au/news/2018/day/1/passport-details-can-now-be-updated-via-email

Comment: When I submitted, the autoreply was 4 weeks and it did take almost 4 weeks(25 days to be exact).

Anyway, I travelled with both my old & new passport. I was flying BLR-SIN-SYD. While boarding SIN-SYD flight, ground staff transferred my visa to the new passport. This took almost 20 mins.

Comment: @sandeepkakkar Correct. Check-in staff (if they know the procedure - some of them don't) can telephone the Australian Government directly to transfer your visa to your new passport.

Comment: Hi @sandeepkakkar my parents have similar situation. I applied yesterday but it says it will take 4 weeks. How risky is it to travel with old and new passport? PS they don't speak English. Also I am ready to wait 4 weeks if I have to, but should I book tickets now or not until it get updated? Did you get any notification when it was updated?

Comment: @TheJavaGuy I don't think it is risky at all but If you can wait, then book tickets considering 4 weeks of buffer for visa transfer to happen. You will get it within 4 weeks for sure.
In my case, I received an email after 25 days confirming that form 929 is processed and visa is transferred.

Comment: Thank you @sandeepkakkar I received mail that they have done it. I called department and they said they can't do anything. Then a friend gave me a email address I mailed my 929 forms and passport copies at that email address and next day I received email saying they have updated it. It will take 48 hours to reflect on VEVO but it shouldn't affect travel.