# Australian eVisa needs to be linked to new passport. Form 929 submitted. Can I travel with old and new passport in case updation is not done?

Tags: visas, australia, passport-renewals

I have an Australian visitor Visa valid till end of Dec 2019. My passport got renewed in February 2019 and I only just got around to informing them of the change via form 929. The reply was it will be updated within approx 4 weeks!

(1)Since I had done a paper application for the visa , I don't have an Immi account. Is that why it is taking so long? If I had done the visa application via Immi account would it have been faster?

(2) If it doesn't get updated fast enough, can I travel with the old and new passports as well as my 929 submission proof and hope the airlines will do the updation before they let me board? Or is that a risk? What are my chances of getting turned back?

(3) The visa itself took 37 days (although they said 29 days)to come and I couldnt travel with my family in December. What are others experiences in getting passport details updated after submitting 929?

Comment: The check-in agent can telephone the Border Operations Centre to transfer your visa across, if they know what to do.  Be prepared to ask the check-in agent to contact the BOC if there are issues.  You can read through section 2.9 of [this manual](https://www.abf.gov.au/help-and-support-subsite/files/advance-passenger-processing.pdf) to understand what will happen.  See also [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129753/how-much-time-it-takes-to-transfer-an-australia-visa-to-a-new-passport-using-for) for another traveller's experience.

Comment: Well the updation finally came around 45 days later! Our trip got postponed so I never had to test whether they would let me in on the old passport.