# Does the 4 weeks processing time for Form 929 start from submission?

Tags: visas, australia

I would like to know which days count to make up the 4 weeks of processing time for the Australian passport/name change visa document Form 929? Does the count start from the day of submission or by the 5 business days?

Answer (score 1):

The processing time starts from the day when the for was received. In [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129753/how-much-time-it-takes-to-transfer-an-australia-visa-to-a-new-passport-using-for) the 4 weeks processing time in the answer is given after the form was received.

Passport details may take time to be reflected:

> Your Form 929 has been processed and your details have been updated in the department’s systems. Please note that Passport changes may take 24-48 hours to be reflected in VEVO. This will not affect your travel.

([Source](https://www.migrationdesk.com/threads/passport-changes-details.45818/))