# How long does Australian online visa transfer take from old to new passport?

Tags: visas, australia, passport-renewals

How long does Australian online visa transfer take from old to new passport. Im an Indian national traveling to Australia in December. I will soon be getting my new passport reissued and will have to transfer my Australian Visa (online) on to the new one, after I update the details in m immi account

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica That question doesn't really deal with how long it takes, though.

Comment: True, but it does illuminate that the amendment can be made online, and the result checked online with the ImmiAccount. By starting the process right away, the OP can have the best possible chance of having the new passport "connected" with the old passport's visa. The dupe is not exact, but can be helpful.

Comment: I'd wager that this falls into the "how long is a piece of string" category. Typically it might take X days, but there could be some reason, in or out of the control of the applicant, that makes this time 10X. Applying ASAP and keeping an eye on ImmiAccount is the 'correct' answer here too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much time it takes to transfer an Australia visa to a new passport using Form 929?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129753/how-much-time-it-takes-to-transfer-an-australia-visa-to-a-new-passport-using-for)